# Changing the title on a TimePicker?

Tags: android, timepicker

I'm trying to look for a solution to change the title on a TimePicker dialog. Right now it says whatever the system time is (ex. "12:23 AM") but I want to change this to something a little more descriptive. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: By TimePicker dialog do you mean the actual TimePickerDialog? Becaues that has a `setTitle(CharSequence text)` method. The TimePickerDialog is what is used in the official tutorial. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html#setTitle(java.lang.CharSequence) - should probably have put that as an aswer, but oh well.

Comment: Oh man Klaus you're a live saver. That worked perfectly! I was worried I would have to create a custom TimePicker or something...you can give an answer and I'll mark it as solved. I have no idea how I didn't discover this, I'm really tired...Thanks so much! :)

Comment: Actually, it sets the title upon initializing the timepicker but as soon as I change a value it will reset back to the date title ("12:23 AM"). I guess I could set the title every time a value is changed but I don't know how. I think I can use a listener?

Comment: Argh, did not see your next comment. Did you add it programatically or through XML? Try both. Otherwise, hmm - not sure what the best way to do so would be. I only see 3 listeners available at first for TimePickerDialog, none of which are really helpful to you. I guess setTitle or similar is called again every time value is changed from Googles own code.

Comment: Yep - look at: http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=core/java/android/app/TimePickerDialog.java;h=a04b9e94405b62b966382f3607342883d802d703;hb=HEAD It updates the time when a new hour and minute is received. You could use the source code from there to create your own Dialog replacing the TimerPickerDialog and simply leave out the part where it automatically updates.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

By request. :)

> By TimePicker dialog do you mean the
>   actual TimePickerDialog? Because that
>   has a `setTitle(CharSequence text)`
>   method. The TimePickerDialog is what
>   is used in the official tutorial. 
>   [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html#setTitle(java.lang.CharSequence)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html#setTitle%28java.lang.CharSequence%29)

Comment: Thanks! :) (not enough characters)

Comment: @Sunandmoon Any time, you saw my comments above as well I guess? I think it might be tough seeing as the Android implementation constantly uses setTitle as new data is received.

Answer (score 6):

This question is rather old, but it shows up on Google results if you search this question. So, I thought I'll post my solution.

`DatePicker` has `setCustomTitle(View view)`, where you can define your own view (e.g. `TextView` with your custom text) to be used as a title. This one does not update when changing values.

Comment: What if I just need to pick the time, and don't care about date?

Answer (score 2):

I dont know how to reply to the comments below question, so I use "Answer".
By looking into source code: [SourceCode](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=core/java/android/app/TimePickerDialog.java;h=a04b9e94405b62b966382f3607342883d802d703;hb=HEAD)

You may realize that OnTimeChangedListener is implemented by TimePickerDialog.
To avoid title changed while adjusting time, you may derived from TimePickerDialog and override  public void onTimeChanged(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute);

Notice, dont call super version, or it will setTitle again...