# Title in TimePickerDialog

Tags: android, kotlin, timepickerdialog

I'm trying to set a title to my TimePickerDialog. 
I've seen couple of examples but I can't achieve to get the result I want.
This is what I'm trying to get.

[image]

But impossible to know how can I place a title like "Please select a date" in the picture.

My code so far:

```
// OnTimeListener
val timeSetListener = TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener { _, hourOfDay, minute ->
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay)
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,minute)
    updateTimeInView()
}

// Opening time picker dialog
val openingTimePickerDialog = TimePickerDialog(this,
   timeSetListener,
   calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),
   calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE),true)
openingTimePickerDialog.setTitle("Opening Hours")
openingTimePickerDialog.show()
```

The `updateTimeInView()` function just change the TextView with the time selected in the picker.

Thanks for your help on this!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5375306/changing-the-title-on-a-timepicker

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this code..

```
 openingTimePickerDialog.setMessage("Opening Hours")
```

Comment: Well played! I could swear I went through all the different possibilities without finding something else than title but apparently, I've missed that one! Thanks for your quick help :-)